# Publish Android Application does not work

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Just created an .apk with the Publish Android Application option, created a keystore with key and uploaded to the Google Play app store. Everything worked, but when I tried to download the app from the app store i got an error message resembling "The application has an incorrect signature". I thought the "Publish Android Application" part of Xamarin.Studio was supposed to fix everything?

I ran the following command on the .apk afterwards: jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs app.apk At the bottom it said the following: This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.

Please help, would love to have the app out today :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was simple. XamarinStudio was setup to use Java1.7, setting it to use Java1.6 fixed it :)